# Synchronously manipulate DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, promise, ecmascript-5

I'm currently developing for a custom browser, which pretty much runs **plain ES5 with Promises** and no support for non-native code at all.
This browser was made to simulate the comportment of an specific hardware whose processing isn't anything close to great. Also, I have very short application size limits.

With this in mind and the task of **showing different views within the same window**, one at a time and only once each time the application is used, I've come out with the idea of reloading only an iframe instead of the whole page.

To do this, I wrote the next code:

```
function loadFrame(page){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.classList.add('hidden');
        iframe.src = page;

        resolve(iframe);
    });
}
function appendTo(elem, parentId){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var parentNode = document.getElementById(parentId);
        parentNode.appendChild(elem);

        resolve(elem);
    });
}
function robOf(elem, id){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var parent = elem.parentNode;
        var doc = elem.contentDocument; // body hasn't loaded so...
        var toImport = doc.getElementById(id); // ... this returns undefined...
        var imported = parent.importNode(toImport, true); //... thus breaking it here
        parent.removeChild(elem);

        resolve(imported);
    });
}

loadFrame('example/myPage.htm')
.then(function(elem){ return appendTo(elem, 'myParentId') })
.then(function(parent){ return robOf(parent, 'myElemId') })
.then(doSomething);
```

The idea behind it is pretty simple:

- create an iframe;
- load it with a local file;
- look the iframe's document for a given element;
- import that given element to my page's document;
- remove the iframe.

However, it bricks. Sometimes **the `iframe` just hasn't loaded in time, so when I define `doc` it's body is empty and I pass `undefined` on `.importNode()`, blowing up the whole stuff**. Thinking that it should be an asynchronous execution problem, I wrapped the function in Promises and end up with the code like it is but the problem stills.
I would like to know exactly what I'm getting wrong about Promises, **why the code isn't working and how can I correct it**, preferably without the use of setTimeout().

Comment: just saying, you can do `elem.contentDocument` --- not that that solves your question.

Comment: Does this custom browser have event handlers? Because `iframe`s have a `load` event you can listen for...

Comment: I don't quite understand how your situation prevents you from using normal DOM manipulation. Presumably you have a document global scope, so can you just track your application state and just... update the DOM to reflect the state the user should be looking at? Why would you need an iframe here?

Comment: @zevee: I'll update my code with it. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: Yes, it has. I haven't thought of it and will try this solution as soon as possible.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I don't quite undestand what you meant, sorry about that. Anyway, I could write down the given element on the very main page and just `hidden` it the whole time, but I thought it would be a messy workaround and that that page's code would get weirder than necessary; that's why I choose to use an `iframe`.

Comment: No, my point is you have a JS environment, right? So keep your application state in JS, not "as DOM elements". Only create/remove DOM elements as needed (similar to how things like react etc. use the DOM *purely* as UI representation. You're not writing a web page, you're writing an application in which the browser, by way of the DOM, is your UI library, so there is no reason to make it pull double duty)

Comment: Ohh, I got it now @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. Sooner I asked my senior about the better way to do it - create the whole thing during run time or just HTML it. He said whatever and that maybe do the HTML thing would be easier so I could go with it. Do you think I should reconsider?

Comment: if your job is interface design, I would probably recommend taking a day to learn React (by running through React's tutorials) and then using that instead, so that use the JS for what it's best at (being the programmatic environment) and using the HTML purely as the UI framework. Because it doesn't sound like you're making web pages, or even web sites, but a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the `load` event on the `<iframe>` to ensure the iframe is never `undefined`.

```js
function loadFrame(page){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
            resolve(this);
        });
        iframe.classList.add('hidden');
        iframe.src = page;
    });
}
```

---

Also, calling `.bind` on your functions may also be cause to some of your issues.

Try instead `.then(function(x) { return functionCall(x,p2,p3) });`

Comment: If I did this, the next Promise would wait until the `load` function resolves? 
About the `bind`, I don't really understand how it's working on my situation. I just got it's basis searching for how to pass parameters to a Promise and that's it. I will change the code to your way. (Which reads a whole lot better than the bind stuff)

Comment: try currying your functions instead of bind and passing params, I guess is more readable

Comment: @AngelSalazar: I guess currying without fat arrows is kind of strange. Code get really pyramidal and verbose thanks to all the `return function(p){ ... }` stuff.